# In Mongoid, does limit(n) take the results from the first n of the results, or the last?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Is it possible to select whether to take the first n of the results or the last n of the results?

Answer (score 1):

You control which `n` docs are included in a `limit(n)` in a couple ways:

1. [`skip(m)`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/#cursor.skip) determines how many docs to skip in the result set before taking the `n`.  If you don't specify a skip value, then the first `n` docs are taken.
2. The sort order can also be used to in conjunction with `limit` as a way of getting the 'last' `n` docs by reversing the sort and then taking the first docs.